# Is there a [fast] way to make QTP's Object Repository case-insensitive?

Tags: qtp, case-sensitive

I have several objects in my repository that no longer match up with my Application Under Test since some labels in my application have changed case.

For example, what was once `Workspace locations` is now `Workspace Locations` with a capital **L**.

I need a fast way to have my objects still be recognized in both the old version of my app and the new version (with the new capitalization). I've found a slow way to make them case-insensitive by inserting `(?i)` into each object's attached-text attribute (see screenshot) but that is amazingly slow, especially when I have several objects to modify across dozens and dozens of tests.

Is there a quick way to make the *entire* test be case-insensitive when matching object attributes?

[image: Case-insensitivity the long way]

Answer (score 1):

**please remember to backup first!**

You could export the object repository to XML through the Object Repository Manager. You can make your changes in the XML, I would suggest to change the regularexpression parameter `<qtpRep:Value RegularExpression="0">` to `"1"` where `<qtpRep:Property Name="title"`. Now the title elements will be seen as regular expressions and regexes are case insensitive by default in QTP.
Note: When you have characters in the title that are special regex characters (like `+`, `?`, `*`, `\` etc.) you have to escape them with a backslash.

Once ready, you can import the changed object repository.

Comment: Normally that would be a good method, but like you said, I would have to go over my code manually to find the special regex characters that I need to escape. So that doesn't sound like too much of a shortcut.

Comment: @Eptin, I understand the situation you are in and I do not have an easy-to-go solution. You say you have to go over you code to manually escape regular expression characters, but you can also do that by code (by replacing `*^${}().?+\|` with the same character with a `\ ` in front of it), but that would not make it less complex I am afraid.